# how to execute imported function in flask on the click of button on html file

Tags: python, ajax, python-2.7, flask

I am new to flask.

I am trying to control a car which have a raspberry pi brain and I am successfully able to do that by execution my script

now I want a web app

In my flask **init** file, I have imported my self-made functions and I have a html file "control.html" .. in that I have 5 buttons. now how to execute my imported function on click of those buttons also the page should not reload.

[code : **init**.py]

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import sys 

''' Importing from my self made file  '''
from keybord_car import carConnect, carRight, carLeft, carFwrd, 
carBack, carStop


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/control')
def control():
    return render_template('control.html')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='192.168.43.205')
```

[code : contol.html]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>controller web page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button >Car connect </button>
    <button >Car forward </button>
    <button >Car back </button>
    <button >Car right </button>
    <button >Car left </button> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some java script functions.
Update this fields in control.html file

```
<body>
    <button onclick=buttonFunction(id="1") >Car connect </button>
    <button onclick=buttonFunction(id="2") >Car forward </button>
    <button onclick=buttonFunction(id="3") >Car back </button>
    <button onclick=buttonFunction(id="4") >Car right </button>
    <button onclick=buttonFunction(id="5") >Car left </button> 
    <p id="ID" ></p>
</body>

<script>

function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

function buttonFunction(id) {
  var url="https://192.168.43.205:8080/handler/";
  var response=httpGet(url+id);
  document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML =response;
}
</script>
```

Add these lines in your python file

```
@app.route("/handler/<ID>",methods=['GET'])
def handler(ID):
    #Your action goes here with corresponding ID
    return "Action Completed | This gets returned to JavaScript Call"
```